# crossplatform builds in gitlab-ci

Tags: python, cross-platform, gitlab-ci

I've got a python project I'm attempting build and deploy to both windows and mac. I'm trying to execute some python scripts and the executable differs between the two platforms. how can I write my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is such a way that it works on both platforms?

I would really like to not duplicate. but that is what I have done so far. 
 thsi is basically what I've done:

```
# this isn't compatible on both platforms!
before_script:
  - python -V
  - python -m venv venv
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
  - test

win_test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - pip install nose
    - nosetests --with-xunit -v --xunit-file=tests/nosetests.xml tests
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: tests/nosetests.xml

osx_test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - osx
  script:
    - pip3 install nose
    - python3 -m nosetests --with-xunit -v --xunit-file=tests/nosetests.xml tests
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: tests/nosetests.xml
```

One problem is the `python` and `pip` are different on the two platforms. Another part I don't like is the logic is duplicated between two platforms as well. This is my first gitlab-ci project, and I'm used to working with Teamcity and Jenkins. Although I didn't do cross-platform builds back then either. Are there some tips to help improve these two issues?